# Wan`t to execute SQL Queries to Outfile on Shutdown mysqld

Tags: mysql

i want to execute some Queries and Log the Response automatically on (of course before) MySQL Normal shutdown, is there any Way to do this?
I try it over Task Scheduler with Trigger on event but that doesn`t works.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the keyword OUTPUT for a parameter in the procedure definition, the procedure can return the current value of the parameter to the calling program when exiting the procedure. To store the value of the parameter in a variable so that the calling program can use it, the calling program must include the keyword OUTPUT when it executes the procedure. For more information on the types of data that can be used as output parameters, see CREATE PROCEDURE (Transact-SQL)